# Selecting rows in Datagridview to textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I am looking to have the contents of the cell's in a datagridview moved to text boxes. However, I can't seem to get it to work. The adding of users to the database button I have tested and works fine, it's just the selection from the data grid view.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TEST
{
    public partial class AddUsers : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=mydb;Integrated Security=True;Connect   Timeout=30");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter adapt;
        int ID = 0;
        public AddUsers()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DisplayData();
        }
        private void selectRow(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ID =    Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }
        //Update Record
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "")
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblLOGIN set USERNAME=@USERNAME,PASSWORD=@PASSWORD where Id=@id", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
                con.Close();
                DisplayData();
                ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Update");
            }
        }
        //New User
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "")
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblLOGIN(USERNAME,PASSWORD) values(@USERNAME,@PASSWORD)", con);
                con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("User created successfully");
            DisplayData();
            ClearData();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter username and password");
        }
    }
    private void DisplayData()
    {
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblLOGIN", con);
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();
    }
            private void ClearData()  
    {  
        textBox1.Text = "";  
        textBox2.Text = "";  
        ID = 0;  
    }
    //Delete user
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ID != 0)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("delete tblLOGIN where Id=@id", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully!");
            DisplayData();
            ClearData();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Delete");
        }
    }

        private void AddUsers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.tblLOGINTableAdapter.Fill(this.usersDataSet.tblLOGIN);
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        AuthenicationForm ss = new AuthenicationForm();
        this.Close();
        ss.Show();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for responding! I wasn't able to get this working either. I was following a guide based here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/1e050f/insert-update-and-delete-record-in-datagridview-c-sharp/

I ended up downloading and opening up his project. It looks like after I made dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick() I needed to go into the datagridview options and select the RowHeaderMouseClick option.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any code to do what you want to do.  Simply bind you `TextBoxes` and/or other controls to the same data source as the grid, e.g.

```
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myBindingSource, "ColumnName")
```

After that, selecting a row in the grid will automatically populate the `TextBox` with the value from the 'ColumnName' column of that row.  Editing the value in the `TextBox` will also automatically update the grid.  That's the whole point of binding, i.e. what happens to one end of the binding also affects the other.  In this case, affecting one control also affects the data source and affecting the data source affects the other control.